# External monitor problems with Asus UX32VD in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, asus, external-monitor

I've posted this [video](http://youtu.be/Y_jY-RpaUPU) where I show one of the problems I'm facing with my UX32VD in regard of external monitors.

As you can see as soon as I plugged the external monitor the laptop screen goes black and the external monitor displays a single color (color changes between red, green and blue).

However this does not always happen. For instance if I reboot the laptop with the external monitor already plugged in I get to use it but not the laptop screen. In the Displays settings the laptop screen it's not even listed.

Other times it just works. The to screens, without any problems. I tried with other to different external monitor and all this apparently random issues repeat, I even tried using HDMI cable instead. Same random behavior.

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190824/laptop-monitor-stays-black-with-an-external-display-connected-to-my-asus-ux32vd) seams to cover one of this issues however the answer did not helped me.

I was forced to use the 3.5.2 kernel in order to use the Intel graphics card else the Gallium something was used. Also I've Bumblebee installed.

Comment: Since you installed Bumblebee I guess your notebook has Nvidia Optimus tecnology?

Comment: Yes, it has, and I'm able to use optirun successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HDMI or display port with Nvidia Optimus because they can only be used with the Nvidia Chip. I'm am having the same problem and bumblebee/optirun doesn't solve it.

You could still use your VGA port if you have one. Another thing you can try is changing to discrete graphics only mode in BIOS but this doesn't always work and if it does it decreases your battery life.

Nvidia is finally [working on drivers](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Hybrid-graphics-support-in-NVIDIA-s-Linux-driver-1697756.html) to fully support Optimus in Linux. The driver will work with Linux kernel 3.5 and XServer 1.13 which are included in Ubuntu 12.10. I hope the driver will be finished soon and solve the pain with Optimus.